# Tell Solr Search Not to Index Parts of My Page

Tags: search, solr, drupal-7

I'm having an issue where inline Javascript is being displayed in `Solr` search results on my Drupal website. Is there a way to hide parts of my code from being indexed by `Solr` similar to how google uses `googleoff:index` and `googleon:index` to keep code from being indexed?

Comment: How do you index your site?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the solr search module for drupal, you can tell solr to index specific fields in your content :
https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr
So your javascript will not get indexed.